# I'm trying to stop an a list from looping since it is empty. All I keep getting is indexerror can't pop from an empty list

Tags: python

I'm doing a school project and I'm making a game that gives the user a choice to choose from a multiple choice option. I want it to show up in a GUI, however the only I know how to get it to show up correctly is by using the .pop method, where it goes down vertically a-e in the GUI.

This is where I get the error:

```
tile_frame = Label(frame, text=tiles_letter.pop())
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

```
import random
import time
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="GAME")
w.pack()

frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=300)
frame.pack()

L1 = Label(root, text="User Name")
L1.pack(side=LEFT)
E1 = Entry(root, bd =5)
E1.pack(side=LEFT)

tiles_letter = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
tiles_letter.reverse()

def add_letter():
    tile_frame = Label(frame, text=tiles_letter.pop())
    tile_frame.pack()
    root.after(500, add_letter)

root.after(0, add_letter)  # add_letter will run as soon as the mainloop starts.
root.mainloop()
```

I do not know how to stop it from popping out of an empty list. I tried using a for..in..loop but it didn't work. Some help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In add_letter, simply check whether there are some letters by using `len(tiles_letters) > 0` :

```
def add_letter():
    if len(tiles_letters) > 0:
        tile_frame = Label(frame, text=tiles_letter.pop())
        tile_frame.pack()
        root.after(500, add_letter)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried that method but I did it outside the function. This corrects the problem.

Comment: Np, how exactly do you mean that ? `if "I got you right":` you wrapped root.after([...]) ?